# send a signal to lighttpd and the signal can be handled by the LD_PRELOADed library

Tags: signals, lighttpd, ld-preload

Hi there:)  I want to run lighttpd server with the LD_PRELOADed library, my LD_PRELOADed library called signal.so and it's code like this:

```
#include <signal.h>

struct sigaction sgSA;

static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *ptr)
{ 
    if(signo == SIGHUP)
        printf("Get a signal -- SIGHUP\n");
}

sgSA.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigemptyset(&sgSA.sa_mask);
sgSA.sa_sigaction = handler;

if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &sgSA, NULL) == -1)
    handle_error("sg sigaction");

raise(SIGHUP);
```

and when I run the program with the library using command:

```
$sudo LD_PRELOAD=./signal.so ./lighttpd -f /usr/local/lighttpd/config/lighttpd.conf
```

It doesn't print the string "Get a signal -- SIGHUP",and I tried this on another simple program instead of the lighttpd server, it indeed can print this string. This pazzled me a lot. So, my question is: how can I do to let the signal be handled by the handler in my LD_PRELOADed library? Tks!

Comment: First of all, check if library is `LD_PRELOAD`-ed at all (setuid binaries ignore it). Also, `lighttpd` may later reset handler so you can intercept `signal` and `sigaction` to see if that's the case.

Comment: I haven't verify the specific resons, but it seems that lighttpd always trap in its' own handler. Therefore, I use the reserved signal SIGUSR2 instead, and it can be resolved. Thank you for your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I thought lighttpd might catch some signals in its code logic, which overrides the `LD_PRELOAD`ed signal handling code. So I searched the lighttpd code base, and found that it did catch some signals such as `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP` in `src/server.c`.

I tried to catch a signal like `SIGUSR2` (not caught by lighttpd) with `LD_PRELOAD`, but it still does not print anything. Using `strace` to print the system call log, it shows we have already entered the preloaded `SIGUSR2` signal handler(`write(1, "Get a signal ...")`). So it seems for some reasons, lighttpd suppressed `printf` from printing logs to the console.

Comment: lighttpd opens *stdin* and *stdout* to /dev/null.  If you want *stderr* to go to console, then do not define server.errorlog or server.breakagelog in lighttpd.conf